# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

```
function cargar_tapete_inicial(mazo) {

        for (let i = 0; i < mazo.length; i++) {
            mazo[i].style.width = "50px";
            mazo[i].style.position = "absolute";
            mazo[i].style.top = paso+'px';
            mazo[i].style.left = paso+'px';
            paso = paso + 3;

            tapete_inicial.appendChild(mazo[i]);
        }
        
        paso = 3;
    }
```

mazo_inicial it starts empty but is filled with the use of some methods

```
/***** INICIO DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES GLOBALES *****/

    // Array de palos y números
    let palos = ["corazones", "picas", "rombos", "treboles"];
    let numeros = ["as", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "jota", "reina", "rey"];

    let paso = 3;

    // Tapetes              
    let tapete_inicial   = document.getElementById("inicial");

    // Mazos
    let mazo_inicial   = [];


    comenzar_juego();
    document.getElementById("reset").onclick = comenzar_juego;


    // Desarrollo del comienzo de juego
    function comenzar_juego() {

        mazo_inicial = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < palos.length; j++) {

                let carta  = document.createElement("img");
                carta.setAttribute("data-nombre", numeros[i]);  
                carta.setAttribute("data-palo", palos[j]); 
                carta.setAttribute("id", numeros[i] + '-' + palos[j]); 
                carta.setAttribute("src", 'img/baraja/' + numeros[i] + '-' + palos[j] + '.png'); 
                
                if(palos[j] == "corazones" || palos[j] == "rombos") {
                    carta.setAttribute("data-color", "rojo"); 
                } else {
                    carta.setAttribute("data-color", "negro");
                }
            
                mazo_inicial.push(carta);

            }   
        } 

        // Barajar
        barajar(mazo_inicial);

        // Dejar mazo_inicial en tapete inicial
        cargar_tapete_inicial(mazo_inicial);
                
        // Arrancar el conteo de tiempo
        arrancar_tiempo();

    }
```

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Solitario</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Título principal -->
    <h1 id="titulo">Juego del solitario</h1>

    <h2 id="marcadores">
        <span>Tiempo: <span id="cont_tiempo"></span></span>
        <span style="display:inline-block; width:200px"></span>
        <span>Movimientos: <span id="cont_movimientos" class=""></span></span>
    </h2>


    <div id="mesa">
        <div class="tapetes_superiores">
            <div id="inicial"   class="tapete"><span id="cont_inicial"   class="contador"></span></div>
            <div id="sobrantes" class="tapete"><span id="cont_sobrantes" class="contador"></span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="receptor1" class="tapete receptor"><span id="cont_receptor1" class="contador"></span></div>
        <div id="receptor2" class="tapete receptor"><span id="cont_receptor2" class="contador"></span></div>
        <div id="receptor3" class="tapete receptor"><span id="cont_receptor3" class="contador"></span></div>
        <div id="receptor4" class="tapete receptor"><span id="cont_receptor4" class="contador"></span></div>            
    </div>  

    <button id="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reiniciar</button>


    <!-- Cargar el script js/solitario.js -->
    <script src="js/solitario.js"></script>

</body>
```

- The div that has id=inicial exists before the js link.
- All tapetes are declared at the beginning of the js as global variables.
- Script link is added at the end of the body.

Nevertheless, the code works and put me the cards in the correct div, but it annoys me to watch that error.

[image]

Can somebody solve this error?

Comment: What is `mazo`, and where and when are you calling your `cargar_tapete_inicial(mazo)`?  Also, `paso`, which you are using inside `cargar_tapete_inicial(mazo)` doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: `mazo` is the array of suffled cards. `cargar_tapete_inicial(mazo)` is called before that. `paso` is defined at the beginning of the code, and allows cards to not be printed one above other. The code is not completed here

Comment: What happens when you do something like this (before your `for` loop): `console.log(mazo)`, and later on, inside the loop: `console.log(mazo[i])`?

Comment: If you onle have one `appendChild` and is called on `tapete_inicial`, the error means that `tapete_inicial` is `null`. Why can it be `null`? for some reasons, like overwriting it, or using different scripts so they don't "merge" their variables inside their scope, or whatever. If you follow the good way of asking questions, we may help you, specially the "Help others reproduce the problem" part: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Shows me all img created, with his custom id, src, top and left style, etc